# Problem at coordinate system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have one image that I filtered it in MATLAB and finally, I saved it in tiff format from MATLAB. My image is RGB. it has three bands;
When I open this image in QGIS, and then go to ‘new print composer’, I do not know why I cannot add coordinate to it. I change ‘CRT’ but still did not work or some black area cover my image.
Do you have any idea?
[image]

Comment: tiff != geotiff. In order to add coordinates, you will have to georeference the image to a map or an already referenced image, most likely manually.

Comment: As Eric says, you need to georeference it.  Just changing the CRT in the layer properties does not georeference an image.  You will find that in the Raster tools.